# SQL Server Management Studio missing when I installed SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, windows-xp, sql-server-2005

For some reason SQL Server Management Studio is missing when I installed SQL Server 2005 Developers Edition. Any reason why or how can i get SQL Server Management Studio on my PC?

My operating system is Windows XP Pro..........

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem, the SQL 2005 install does not often install manamgent studio, even though you tell it to install all the tools. The easiest way to get it installed is to look on the CD, or setup file location and run:

```
{drive}\ENGLISH\SQL2005\DEVELOPER\SQL Server\Tools\Setup\SqlRun_Tools.exe
```

if your using the X64 version use:

```
{drive}\ENGLISH\SQL2005\DEVELOPER\SQL Server x64\Tools\Setup\SqlRun_Tools.exe
```

[Source](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/ssmith/archive/2008/03/21/SQL-2005-Tools-Install-Experience-is-the-suck.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

edit: My mistake, my lack of coffee had me read SQL Server 2005 Express, not Developer. There are some workarounds for Dev edition here:

http://aspadvice.com/blogs/ssmith/archive/2008/03/21/SQL-2005-Tools-Install-Experience-is-the-suck.aspx

http://aspadvice.com/blogs/name/archive/2007/09/24/Installing-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-with-SQL-Server.aspx