# sql server 2008 management studio download?

Tags: sql-server

Anyone know if there is a separate download for MS SQL 2008 mgmt studio, that includes just the client tools?

EDIT: Sorry, not the express version, the full-blown one. and if there is a 64bit one, even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en) is probably what you're after.

**[Edit]**

Ah, I now see you don't want Express.

Not a sep. installer, but if you pop in the SQL 2008 disc and start the installer you will get the option to just to do the client tools. I think you have to grunt through the pre-reqs part first though.

Comment: Regarding the 64 bit client, see if the accepted answer on this topic helps: http://serverfault.com/questions/40985/sql-server-management-studio-missing-when-i-installed-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 2):

No, the only one that is freely available is Management Studio Express.  Anything else requires the full version of Management Studio that can be installed from the normal SQL Server installation media.